# Showing group managers a list of pending users

Tags: organic-groups, 7

We're using [Drupal Commons 3.3](http://drupal.org/project/commons) and our group managers have been asking for a single view of all pending users. Email is becoming too cumbersome and unmanageable. Is there a View or Pane that I can add showing our Group Managers which users should become members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the View `Commons Contributors - Group (User)`, I cloned the Display `group homepage`

[image]

In this new content pane, I then added a footer with a link below. This will take the user to the Administer Group/People page.

```
<a href="/group/node/!1/admin/people">Manage memberships</a>
```

[image]

Caveat: On Panels (via /admin/structure/types/manage/group/panelizer/page_manager/content), I set view permission to: *Logged in User has "Approve or Deny permission for this group"*

[image]